# Scanstate.exe Migration Error

Tags: windows, windows-7, migration, ms-dos

I'm trying to create a migration store on a server using Scanstate and this is the error I recieve:
C:\USMT>scanstate.exe \(Server_Name)\migration\mystore /f:migdocs.xml /f:
migapp.xml /v:13 /f:scan.log

Failed.
  An error occurred processing the command line.
  scanstate.exe \svdataitfl1\migration\mystore ##ERROR## --> /f:migdocs.xml /f
migapp.xml /v:13 /f:scan.log
  Undefined or incomplete command line option

ScanState return code: 11

I can't seem to find the answer to this...need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read [scanstate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749015%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) Syntax rules, log files are preceeded by l (lowercase L) and config options preceeded by i, the f option doesn't exist for what I can tell so try

```
scanstate.exe \(Server_Name)\migration\mystore /i:migdocs.xml /i: migapp.xml /v:13 /l:scan.log
```